# Filter Debug statements in the Output Window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, system.diagnostics, azure-application-insights, output-window

I'm finding my Output Window's content quite unpleasant to use, as the window is about 90% full of debug lines from IIS Express and from Application Insights. Ideally I would like to filter the Debug sources that write to that window, but maybe I can configure either source to not write so much debug data, e.g. maybe set a higher minimum level like `Error` vs. what looks like `Trace`, or at least `Info`.

What can I do so I can more easily see my own debug statements and important stuff, like WPF binding errors?

I've found an excellent solution for most unwanted info in the Output Window in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31969601/8741), but there is still a lot of clutter from `ApplicationInsights`. Is there no way to configure this locally to only write at level `Error`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's no error level concept for ApplicationInsights output all up (some things like custom events, metrics, etc, don't have the concept of an error level).

if you want to disable the output, you can either set `DeveloperMode` to false, or use `TelemetryDebugWriter.IsTracingDisabled = true;` to disable output.

(disabling output will make any of the application insights tools in visual studio while debugging no longer function, though.  the AI VS extension is watching the output window for those events to power content in Diagnostics Tools window, debug search, and local CodeLens scenarios)

Comment: Aah, thanks. The AI output is tolerable, because I often spot errors there, but having turned off all load, unload, process exit, thread exit output, the window is much less cluttered.

Comment: i once prototyped a checkbox there for "hide application insights output", would that be a useful thing?

Comment: That checkbox would be great. I could maybe even extend the concept to "hide iis express output".